# AngularJS - Child directive uses same data as parent. How to share?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a child directive that requires the same data as some of the parent pages that use it.

What is the best way to share data?

Should the child directive make the same API call as the parent?

Or should the parent send data to the directive via attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it depends.

If the parent and child directive are ever going to be re-used separately (meaning you could use one without the other) then you would DEFINITELY want to use attributes API to pass data into the child directive.

If they are always going to be used together, then you could do one of the following:

- Use attributes to pass the value
- Remove the isolate scope from the child and just have the child scope inherit the values from the parent scope. I hate it when people do this, but to each their own.
- Have a service that caches the values, and they both call the service and get the same values back.
- You could have the parent scope broadcast the data down to it's children using the scope eventing system.

All of these will work. You need to discuss with your team what they like the most and what you all think you should adopt as your regular pattern. After that, you just implement away.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I'm very interested in approach (3) whereby the service caches the values so both parent and child can use. In fact, I posted a similar question as well. How is this achieved? Do I simply declare variables from within the service for callers to use? Would this go against any Angular rules of preaching to avoid storing data in services? @aaronfrost

Comment: If the data is massive, then you could potentially create a memory leak. So, in your code where you call the service to get the code, you may want to add a $scope.$on('$destroy', fn) listener, and in the destroy function, you can call the service and remove the data from the service. 

The one thing that I recommend is never returning the data directly. Always return a promise that is resolved with the data. That is the pattern that you should follow. 

Any other questions?

Comment: Also, look at the $cacheFactory. It will help you use a cache that expires and such. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache

Comment: Thanks @aaronfrost. How would you return a promise versus reading the data directly? For example, I use a promise to fetch the data from the external API, and once complete I will store in my service: self.userName = result.data.userName, self.userID = result.data.userID, etc. Then outsiders can just call myService.userName and myService.userID, since these were already set when the initial call was made. Will this work? I'll try and edit my answer to reflect this

Comment: if you are using angular 1.4 you can simply do: 

    if(self.userName) return $q.resolve(self.userName);

That would allow you to always code to the api of a promise, instead of sometimes returning the data and other times returning a promise. You know?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the explanation and for the code sample, it's a lot clearer to me. I'm going to try this out and report back @aaronfrost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91021/discussion-between-aaronfrost-and-ricky).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you described the right solution. It is better to pass data to directive trough attributes, and make directive only display that. 
But if you still want to make a call to api in the directive, then I would recommend to extract api call to service, and cache promise inside the service. This [plugin](https://github.com/chrisronline/angular-promise-cache) can be useful.

Comment: Thanks @Evgeniy. My API calls are currently performed through a service. However, it would still mean I'm calling the APIs twice. I'll check out the plug-in to see if it helps, however I was curious if there was a pure angular way to approach this. I feel like this would be a common issue